# Tab reload in Safari after extension installation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, safari, safari-extension

Is there any equivalent in safari extension of such a code:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) { 
        chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id);
    });
This code comes from Chrome.
```

I would like to put this code to the global.html. I want to immediately reload a page after extension installation.

Answer (score 6):

```
var activeTab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab;
activeTab.url = activeTab.url;
```

Comment: Thank you form reply. Will it resend $_POST request?

Comment: I don't know. As far as I call tell, it's identical to copying the URL from the tab's address bar, pasting it back in, and hitting Enter.